# Erro com findViewById na classe de envio de e-mail por aplicativo

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um apk onde tem formulários que serão enviados por e-mail. Dai minha classe para mudança de janela tava assim:

[image: erro]
Ao adicionar os métodos necessários para que eu possa enviar emails direto da minha aplicação, encontrei esses erros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: erro3]

Comment: Para atribuir seu `context` seria desta forma: `context = Solicitacoes.this`!

Comment: Solicitaçoes é um Fragment?

Comment: tava em fragment.. ai coloquei em activity, consegui rodar sem bugs, porem nao esta enviando email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa adicionar sua View antes do findViewById

```
Button login = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.enviar);
```

Comment: Nada tem haver com o erro apresentado mas julgo que você tem razão, esse é mesmo o problema.